# Setup php.ini for Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm tring to setup for the first time Symfony framework. After I had installed,it advise me to modify in my php.ini:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level
realpath_cache_size
```

but they are not in my php.ini file.

Least it advise me to install a Php accelerator, how can I do?

Comment: You should setup APC & XDebug. Search for documentation on google

Comment: Which php.ini must I modify? There are more than one. I use wamp server @ApulGupta

Comment: `apt-get update` and `apt-get install php-apc` (extract from [here](http://www.whaleblubber.ca/apc-alternative-php-cache/))

Comment: @StefanoMaglione, You should check the loaded ini using `phpinfo();`

Comment: @RogerGuasch how would he run apt-get update and apt-get install php-apc when hes using windows? (Wamp)

Comment: @Xatenev Why do you suppose that is using windows? but if he is in windows can't install the way I'm saying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install [APC](http://php.net/manual/de/book.apc.php) & [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) like @ApulGupta already said.

In WAMP you have 3 `php.ini` files.

```
/wamp/bin/php (php.ini)
/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.10/bin (php.ini)*
/wamp/bin/php (phpForApache.ini)
```

First one is your real php.ini which Symfony2 refers to.

The second one is used by command line scripts and stuff.

The third one has something to do with swapping, but that doesn't matter for you (you should **definetly** not touch it :)).

Answer (score 0):

Install Xcache. Xcache is a free and open PHP opcode cacher for caching and optimizing PHP intermediate code. It's similar to other PHP opcode cachers, such as eAccelerator and APC.

```
apt-get install php5-xcache
```